# How to change a page url

Tags: java, html, spring, url

I have this simple controller:

```
  @RequestMapping("changeTestCase")
public ModelAndView modifyTestCase(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("changeTestCase");
    model.addObject("testCases",TestCase.getTestCases());
    model.addObject("types", TestType.getTypes());
    return model;
}
```

This gives me the page url `http://localhost:8080/changeTestCase`. What I actually want is `http://localhost:8080/testCase/change` . How do I do this ? Do I need to create a folder called testCase and put a page called change there or can I  just change the name?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just change the mapping to `@RequestMapping("testCase/change")` and keep everything else as it is.